# Word taskpane add-in is disabled when working with an rtf or odt document

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, office-js, office-addins, word-addins

I am trying to develop a Word add-in which is written in JS and makes use of the OfficeJS library. When I open an rtf or odt file, the taskpane button to open the add-in is disabled. However, the plugin runs fine when working with docx files.

[Takepane button when looking at odt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAlIx.png)

The Office add-in documentation doesn't make me aware of any limitations regarding the aforementioned file types.

Does anyone have any workarounds to get this working?

Answer (score 1):

This is expected. Office add-ins do not support RTF or ODT formatted files. You will have to convert the file to docx to run add-ins.